# How can I scale an object in out with rotation using a key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScaleRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 minScale;
    public Vector3 maxScale;
    public float duration;

    private bool scaling = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(maxScale, duration));
    }

    public IEnumerator ScaleOverSeconds(Vector3 scaleTo, float seconds)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 startingScale = transform.localScale;
        while (elapsedTime < seconds)
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        transform.localScale = scaleTo;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if(scaling == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(minScale, duration));

                scaling = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it scales to max and when `S` is pressed to min.
But I want when I press on `S` it will scale to max/min each time pressing the `S` key.
And also I want when the object scales that it will rotate by 180 degrees according to the scaling duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully get the rotation part but as I understand you rather want to toggle the scaling so something like e.g.

```
// flag for the scale direction
private bool scaleToMax;

// flag for checking if already scaling to avoid concurrent routines
private bool alreadyScaling;

private void Start()
{
    // initial scale to max
    ToggleScale();
}

private void Update()
{
    // first check if another routine is already running
    // -> ignore/lock input
    if(!alreadyScaling && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        ToggleScale();
    }
}

// Invert the scale direction and start aroutine
private void ToggleScale()
{
    if(alreadyScaling)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Already scaling -> Ignored!", this);
        return;
    }

    // invert the scale direction
    scaleToMax = !scaleToMax;
    
    StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(scaleToMax ? maxScale : minScale, duration));
    // This is basically a shortcut for doing something like
    //Vector3 targetScale;
    //if(scaleToMax)
    //{
    //    targetScale = maxScale;
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    targetScale = minScale;
    //}
    //StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(targetScale, duration));
}

private IEnumerator ScaleOverSeconds(Vector3 scaleTo, float seconds)
{
    // block concurrent routines
    if(alreadyScaling) yield break;
    alreadyScaling = true;

    var startingScale = transform.localScale;
    var initialRotation = transform.rotation;

    // Here it is a bit unclear which axis you want to rotate on but you could do e.g.
    var targetRotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);

    var elapsedTime = 0f;
    while (elapsedTime < seconds)
    {
        var factor = elapsedTime / seconds;
        // Just fyi here you can also add some smoothing at the beginning and end e.g.
        //factor = SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, factor);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(initialRotation, targetRotation, factor);

        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        // Unless you explicitly need the end of frame yielding null is just fine
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.localScale = scaleTo;
    transform.rotation = targetRotation;

    // allow the next routine to start
    alreadyScaling = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make this you can just use else operator in your void Update()

And for rotation Unity uses Quaternions, which are math abstractions with 3 imaginary units and one real unit. If you want, you can read about it more

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html

but it's really not easy to understand so Unity provides localEulerAngles for easier rotation. It works just as Vector3 (you can see it in inspector in Transform.rotation field)

So, what will do our changed code:
if object has max scale (scaling == true), it will change to min scale and rotate to 180 degrees (clockwise) by Y-axis

And if object has min scale (scaling == false), it will change to max scale and rotate to 180 degrees (also clockwise) by Y-axis

If you want to change second rotation to counterclockwise, you can change second rotation from 180 degrees to -180 degrees.

Also it's good idea to not change size if size is changing right now. For example if object is becoming bigger right now and we press 'S' to make it smaller, it will be at the same time trying to become bigger and smaller and the result could be very strange!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScaleRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    //It's better to use private fields. If you want to see it in inspector, use SerializeField
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 minScale;

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 maxScale;

    [SerializeField]
    private float duration;

    private bool scaling = true;

    //Variable to set angle to rotate your object (in degrees)
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationAngle = 180.0f;

    //Bool which says: if object is changing it's size right now
    private bool isInProcess = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(maxScale, duration));
    }

    public IEnumerator ScaleOverSeconds(Vector3 scaleTo, Vector3 rotateTo, float seconds)
    {
        isInProcess = true;
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 startingScale = transform.localScale;
        Vector3 startingRotation = transform.localEulerAngles;
        //If you want, you can change axis of rotation or angle or everything you want. But what I do - I rotate by Y-axis for 180 degrees

        while (elapsedTime < seconds)
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startingScale, scaleTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.lerp(startingRotation, rotateTo, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            //You can use yield return null instead of yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame() - this will do the same, but it's easier to write
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.localScale = scaleTo;
        transform.localEulerAngles = rotateTo;
        isInProcess = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            //Check if object is not changing it's scale right now
            if(!isInProcess){
                //Use if(scaling) instead of if(scaling == true) - this means the same, but it's more readable
                if(scaling)
                {
                    Vector3 rotateTo = transform.localEulerAngles + new Vector3(0, rotationAngle, 0);
                    StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(minScale, rotateTo, duration));
                    //Remove scaling = false (we will paste it later)
                }
                //Add there else operator
                else {
                    //If you want to change rotation to counterclockwise, change '+' to '-'
                    Vector3 rotateTo = transform.localEulerAngles + new Vector3(0, rotationAngle, 0);
                    StartCoroutine(ScaleOverSeconds(maxScale, rotateTo, duration));
                }   
                //Change scaling value. If you want, you can move this line into ScaleOverSeconds coroutine
                scaling = !scaling; 
            }
        }         
    }
}
```